# Prolog program that swaps the two halves of a list

Tags: prolog

I am new to this language and am having trouble coming up with a solution to this problem. The program must implement the following cases.

- Both variables are instantiated:

  ```
  pivot( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [5,6,7,4,1,2,3] ).`
  ```

  yields a true/yes result.
- Only Before is instantiated:

  ```
  pivot( [1,2,3,4,5,6], R ).
  ```

  unifies `R = [4,5,6,1,2,3]` as its one result.
- Only After is instantiated:

  ```
  pivot(L, [1,2]).
  ```

  unifies `L = [2,1]` as its one result.
- Neither variable is instantiated:

  ```
  pivot(L, R).
  ```

  is undefined (since results are generated arbitrarily).

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by _**pivot**_?

Comment: Swap the halves.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and make that clear.

Comment: What about `[1,2,3]`?

Answer (score 0):

If by ***pivot***, you mean to split the list in 2 and swap the halves, then something like this would work.

First, consider the normal case: If you have an instantiated list, pivoting it is trivial. You just need to

- figure out half the length of the list
- break it up into

  - a prefix, consisting of that many items, and
  - a suffix, consisting of whatever is left over
- concatenate those two lists in reverse order

Once you have that, everything else is just a matter of deciding which variable is bound and using that as the source list.

It is a common Prolog idiom to have a single "public" predicate that invokes a "private" worker predicate that does the actual work.

Given that the problem statement requires that at least one of the two variable in your `pivot/2` must be instantiated, we can define our public predicate along these lines:

```
pivot( Ls , Rs ) :- nonvar(Ls), !, pivot0(Ls,Rs) .
pivot( Ls , Rs ) :- nonvar(Rs), !, pivot0(Rs,Ls) .
```

If `Ls` is bound, we invoke the worker, `pivot0/2` with the arguments as-is. But if `Ls` is unbound, and `Rs` is bound, we invoke it with the arguments reversed. The cuts (`!`) are there to prevent the predicate from succeeding twice if invoked with both arguments bound (`pivot([a,b,c],[a,b,c]).`).

Our private helper, `pivot0/2` is simple, because it knows that the 1st argument will always be bound:

```
pivot0( Ls , Rs ) :-   % to divide a list in half and exchange the halves...
  length(Ls,N0)      , % get the length of the source list
  N is N0 // 2       , % divide it by 2 using integer division
  length(Pfx,N)      , % construct a unbound list of the desired length
  append(Pfx,Sfx,Ls) , % break the source list up into its two halves
  append(Sfx,Pfx,Rs)   % put the two halves back together in the desired order
  .                    % Easy!
```

Answer (score 0):

In swi-prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

pivot_using_dcg3(Lst, LstPivot) :-
    list_first(Lst, LstPivot, L1, L2, IsList),
    phrase(piv3_up(L1), L1, L2),
    % Improve determinism
    (IsList = true -> ! ; true).

piv3_up(L), string(Ri), string(M), string(Le) --> piv3(L, Le, M, Ri).

piv3([], [], [], Ri) --> [], remainder(Ri).
piv3([_], [], [H], Ri) --> [H], remainder(Ri).
piv3([_, _|Lst], [H|T], M, Ri) --> [H], piv3(Lst, T, M, Ri).

% From 2 potential lists, rearrange them in order of usefulness
list_first(V1, V2, L1, L2, IsList) :-
    (   is_list(V1) ->
        L1 = V1, L2 = V2,
        IsList = true
    ;   L1 = V2, L2 = V1,
        (is_list(L1) -> IsList = true ; IsList = false)
    ).
```

Is general and deterministic, with good performance:

```
?- time(pivot_using_dcg3(L, P)).
% 18 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (88% CPU, 402441 Lips)
L = P, P = [] ;
% 8 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (86% CPU, 238251 Lips)
L = P, P = [_] ;
% 10 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (87% CPU, 275073 Lips)
L = [_A,_B],
P = [_B,_A] ;
% 10 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (94% CPU, 313391 Lips)
L = [_A,_B,_C],
P = [_C,_B,_A] ;
% 12 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (87% CPU, 321940 Lips)
L = [_A,_B,_C,_D],
P = [_C,_D,_A,_B] ;
% 12 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (86% CPU, 345752 Lips)
L = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E],
P = [_D,_E,_C,_A,_B] ;
% 14 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (88% CPU, 371589 Lips)
L = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F],
P = [_D,_E,_F,_A,_B,_C] ;

?- numlist(1, 5000000, P), time(pivot_using_dcg3(L, P)).
% 7,500,018 inferences, 1.109 CPU in 1.098 seconds (101% CPU, 6759831 Lips)
```

The performance could be improved further, using difference lists for the final left-middle-right append, and cuts (sacrificing generality).